# What is the difference between throttling and load balancing?

Tags: rest, api, kotlin, load-balancing, http4k

I am trying to make a REST API with Kotlin/http4k and one of the specs is that it should implement throttling.

Are there any differences between throttling and load balancing?

Comment: If you throttle something, you intentionally deny it even though you may have capacity to deal with it. With load balancing, you're usually trying to handle as much at once as possible

Answer (score 2):

**Throttling** is a process that regulates the processing rate.

**Load balancing** is a process that distributes the processing over available resources.

With **throttling**, you can adjust the producing rate to match consumer's capabilities, so it isn't asked to process more than it can handle.

With **load balancing**, you can distribute the processing between multiple consumers so none of them gets overloaded.

You can combine the two techniques together.